# trying to add vote feature to my projcet & i'm adding 1 vote, how can check user already added or not and how can i save their data into database

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views

Here is my model :

```
class Vote(models.Model):
answer = models.ForeignKey(Answer, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=False)
author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=False)

def __str__(self):
    return str(self.answer)

class Answer(models.Model):
question = models.ForeignKey(Question, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='answers')
answer = models.CharField(max_length=1000, default="", blank=False)
author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
createdAt = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
votes = models.IntegerField(default=0)

def __str__(self):
    return str(self.answer)
```

here is my serializer :

```
class VoteSerailizer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
class Meta:
    model = Vote
    fields = '__all__'
```

here is my views :

```
@api_view(['POST'])
@permission_classes([IsAuthenticated])
def upvote(request, pk):
    answer = get_object_or_404(Answer, id=pk)
    if answer['author'] == request.user:
        return Response({
            'error':"You cannot vote twice."
        })
    answer.votes += 1
    answer.save()
    return Response({
        'details':'Vote added'
    }, status.HTTP_202_ACCEPTED)
```

It shows error "TypeError: 'Answer' object is not subscriptable" in my views loop.

and i need to add author and answer in my database ie. model, how can i do that

Comment: Can you share the `Answer` model as well?

Comment: yes i did, have a look.

Answer (score 1):

Well you have a `Vote` model, but you don't seem to be using it (effectively). If you don't track who has voted already, you of course can not know.

I would advise *not* to add the number of votes to an `Answer`: you can determine that when needed through *annotation*.

What you can do is just check if the `Vote` already exists, and if not add one, so:

```
@api_view(['POST'])
@permission_classes([IsAuthenticated])
def upvote(request, pk):
    __, created = Vote.objects.get_or_create(author=request.user, answer_id=pk)
    if not created:
        return Response({'error': 'You cannot vote twice.'})
    return Response({'details': 'Vote added'}, status.HTTP_202_ACCEPTED)
```

so the `Answer` model then looks like:

```
from django.conf import settings


class Answer(models.Model):
    question = models.ForeignKey(
        Question, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='answers'
    )
    answer = models.CharField(max_length=1000, default='', blank=False)
    author = models.ForeignKey(
        settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True
    )
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    # no votes

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.answer)
```

and when you need the number of votes, annotate the `Answer`(s) with:

```
from django.db.models import Count

Answer.objects.annotate(votes=Count('vote'))
```

---

> **Note**: normally the name of the fields in a Django model are written in *snake_case*, not *PascalCase*, so it should be: `created_at` instead of <s>`createdAt`</s>.

---

> **Note**: It is normally better to make use of the [**`settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/settings/#std:setting-AUTH_USER_MODEL) to refer to the user model, than to use the [**`User`** model <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.User) directly. For more information you can see the [*referencing the `User` model* section of the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/topics/auth/customizing/#referencing-the-user-model).

Comment: That views bit complicated to me, can you write that in a simple way. I'm new.

Comment: @RohitGajula: what's complicated about it, we try to fetch the vote, and in case it does not exist, create one at the database side. Next we check if Django had to create one. If so, we're fine, if not, it means the vote was already there, so we report that.

Comment: yess on it, almost there.